# Consolidate autofill Doc with Sheet duplicate values

Tags: google-analytics, google-docs, autofill

I'd like to have a respondent complete a form, and which they will be able to view their information via a Google Doc, and update any information by clicking on the URL Form inserted in the Doc.

1. So I found a way to get the Form URL into Sheet (while populating the Form's data in Sheet).
2. Then a Doc is created with the information from the Form (basically populated from Sheet), and all Docs saved in a specific folder.
3. If a respondent wants to update a specific information, they can just click on the URL Form (populated inside the Doc via a placeholder), resubmit the form, then the Doc will be updated accordingly (thus they don't have to update the Doc directly).

Thanks to Jeffery Everhart's tutorial (https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2020/09/29/auto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data/), I somehow managed to get the first part, but I'm missing the remaining.

The issue I'm having is the following:

- Too many files are created in the folder. Whenever I run the script, it goes through the entire Sheet and recreates all the Doc files. So the existing files are not replaced.
- If a respondent resubmits an existing form, it will create a new Doc (Sheet seems to capture and keep only the latest info, that's great), but the old Docs will remain in the folder.
- If a respondent submits a new form (not existing one), I would like to have this new Form data in Sheet, however I would like to have the information consolidated in 1 single Doc. Meaning if a respondent submits 3 forms, I would have 3 different Google Docs (with the current script), but I would like to have 1 Doc with all information consolidated, line by line (each line displaying a form's data). (that's the tricky part and most important to what i'm looking for)

Here is my script and what seems to work so far. But I've been unsuccessful to replace existing Doc with new ones (when a respondent resubmits an existing form), and most importantly consolidate information in a single Doc when the same respondent submits multiple forms....

```
    function onFormSubmit() {
      var form = FormApp.openById('1CYeWAuN_PyHzDZyeqErwWkPNLHzXzgPp_RCotoX6ZQw'); 
      deleteTrigger();  
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sZ2- SE93E8gSyYycV23euEwhbWLsq2EL2vssWAJzx7I').getSheetByName('Réponses au formulaire 1');

      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var urlCol = 6; 
      var responses = form.getResponses();
      var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
        urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
      }
      for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {
        resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
      }
      sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
  
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
        .forForm(form)
        .onFormSubmit()
        .create();
    }

    function deleteTrigger() {
      var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
      for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
        ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
      }
      createNewGoogleDocs();
    }

    function createNewGoogleDocs() {
      // Document template ID
      const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1KZTL3H6nh2Qia5UtLi8TMeCD3Dh_dqmOz7n980-    J8_8');

      // Folder ID where completed documents are stored
      const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1YUPkbt-niAXxA1OrqgZCIdw6gNUeCY_7');

      // Accessing the spreadsheet by its ID
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sZ2-    SE93E8gSyYycV23euEwhbWLsq2EL2vssWAJzx7I').getSheetByName('Réponses au formulaire 1');

      // Retrieve all values as a 2D array
      const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

      // Process each spreadsheet row
      rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
        // Skip header row
        if (index === 0) return;

        // Check if a document link already exists in the 'Document Link' column
        if (row[13]) {
          // If a document link exists, find and delete the existing document in the folder
          const files = destinationFolder.getFilesByName(`${row[1]} ${row[2]} Basic infos`);
          while (files.hasNext()) {
            const file = files.next();
            // Delete the existing file
            file.setTrashed(true);
          }
        }

    // Function to escape potential regular expression characters
    function escapeRegExp(string) {
      return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
    }

        // Create a copy of the template document in the destination folder
        const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]} ${row[2]} Basic infos`,     destinationFolder);

        // Open the copied document
        const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

        // Get the document's body for editing
        const body = doc.getBody();

        // Format the date, but for some reason it displays 'invalid date' still
        const friendlyDate = new Date(row[5]).toLocaleDateString();

        // Replacing placeholders from Doc template with actual data from the spreadsheet row
        body.replaceText('{{First name}}', escapeRegExp(row[1]));
        body.replaceText('{{Last name}}', escapeRegExp(row[2]));
        body.replaceText('{{City}}', escapeRegExp(row[3]));
        body.replaceText('{{Date of birth}}', escapeRegExp(friendlyDate));

        // Save and close the document
        doc.saveAndClose();

        // Get the URL of the new document
        const url = doc.getUrl();

        // Update the 'Document Link' column in the spreadsheet with the document URL
        sheet.getRange(index + 1, 7).setValue(url);
      });
    }
```